# SAS use an array to search through variables and then populate new variables

Tags: arrays, macros, sas

I have a data set with diagnosis codes, and each observation has multiple diagnosis codes, up to 95 (variables dx1-dx95), some of the dx codes are numeric but some are e codes (they have an E before the number, and then they become character variables).  I need to write code that will look in all 95 dx code variables and pull out each time there’s an e code and make new variables called ecode1-ecode# (however many ecodes there are in that observation).

For example one observation might have dx1=999 dx2=E100 dx3=878 and dx4=E202, I need to make new variables ecode1=E100 ecode2=202.  The code I wrote yesterday got me close, but what I wrote makes the above example ecode2=E100 ecode4=E202.  The ecode variable # ends up being the same as the dx # instead of starting at 1 and counting up.

Here’s what I wrote yesterday:

```
**//array to pull out ecodes from dx1-dx95//**; 
data ecodes; 
set injurycodes; 
*array to create new ecode variables; 
array ecode{95}$ ecode1-ecode95; 
*array to pull out ecodes; 
array dxcode{95} dx1-dx95; 
do i=1 to 95; 
if 'E0000' le dxcode{i} le 'E9999' then ecode{i}=dxcode{i};
end; 
drop i; 
run;
```

I know the problem right now is the ecode{i}=dxcode{i} piece.  This is pulling out the Ecodes, but they aren't starting with ecode1, ecode2, etc.

Updated code:

```
data ecodes; 
set injurycodes; 
array ecode{95}$ ecode1-ecode95; 
array dxcode{95} dx1-dx95; 
j=0;
DO i=1 TO 95;
  IF SUBSTR(CATT(dxcode{i}),1,1)="E" THEN DO;
     ecode{j}=dxcode{i};
     j=j+1;
  END;
END;
run;
```

Now I'm getting "invalid second argument to function SUBSTR"

Comment: DX codes are almost always stored as characters, why do you want numeric ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the first character of dxcode with `SUBSTR`, and use `j` to loop ecode.

```
j=0;
DO i=1 TO 95;
  IF SUBSTR(CATT(dxcode{i}),1,1)="E" THEN DO;
     ecode{j}=dxcode{i};
     j=j+1;
  END;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I don't want to get rid of the E.  I basically want to look at all 95 dxcodes and pull out all the ones that start with E (keeping the E at the front of the code) and make a set of new ecode variables that just include those dxcode variables that had the E.

Comment: I'm getting "invalid second argument to fuction SUBSTR".  Will post the new code.

Comment: That's just a warning you got when dxcode{i} is blank. You can ignore it or you should try to add a if test before the SUBSTR.

Comment: @Jfly why not get rid of CATT and SUBSTR and use the FIRST function.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is you need to keep a separate counter variable to use to index into the output array.

```
data ecodes; 
  set injurycodes; 
  array ecode(95) $5; 
  array dx (95) ; 
  j=1;
  do i=1 to dim(dx);
    if dx(i)=:'E' then do;
      ecode(j) = dx(i);
      j=j+1;
    end;
  end;
  drop i j;
run;
```